# Struts setting radio button value from javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2, radio-button, struts

I have a Struts radio button which I am trying to set from JavaScript, with no success.

Below is my code and options I have tried.

**Radio Button**

```
<s:radio name = "myrdb" 
           id = "myrdb" 
         list = "#{'true':'Yes','false':'No'}" 
      onclick = "rdbFunction(this.value)" />
```

**Option tried:**

- `document.getElementById('myrdb').value = 'true';`
- `document.getElementById('myrdb').attr('value', 'true');`
- `document.getElementById('myrdb').set('value', 'true');`

Comment: You are rendering two radio buttons. Do you think they will have same `id`? Look at the generated HTML.

Comment: @AleksandrM i looked at the radio buttons and they do not have the same ids its different. Would i need to get the radio button by name?

Comment: ok great i got it to work needed to get the id created by (myrdbtrue) the dom and set checked = true

Comment: Good that you've solved it.

Comment: @AleksandrM yes i did with your help thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Code seems ok to me and this should work if nothing more (bad) is happening. With no output neither errors, I only could recomend you:

- Make sure javascript is correctly imported at the head tag on your jsp.
- Make sure the onclick event is really calling you rdbFunction function(debug or insert an alert).
- I've had some problems with includes of jsp and javascript. To be sure this is not impacting you try also to define the rdbFunction inside the jsp.

Comment: The rdbFunction works perfect I am just not sure why am not not able to set the value of the radio button. There are no errors however the code breaks into debug mode (firebug)

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myrdb").checked = true;
```

In jQuery

```
$("#myrdb").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: This is for checkbox or radio button?

Comment: both, but with radio you need to target the id of the choosen one (read AleksandrM comment)